# React Native: componentWillUpdate not called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm creating a React Native app using React Navigation and Redux.

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {

state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    errors: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }
}

onPressLogin() {
    this.props.signIn(this.state.email, this.state.password);
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log("component will update");

    if (nextProps.signedIn) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoggedIn');
    }
}

render() {
    if (this.props.signedIn) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoggedIn');
    }

    return(<View>...</View);
```

this.props.signIn() is a Redux action, which for now just updates the state as such: { signedIn: true }. The following code is where I pass the Redux actions and state as props.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        signedIn: state.authReducer.signedIn,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen);
```

When the action is fired, the state updates as I would expect and render() is called. If I put the navigation code in the render() function everything works fine. To make the code cleaner, I want to move it into componentWillUpdate() but this function is not firing. The console log never gets printed to the console.

Here is my action and my reducer.

Action:

```
export const SIGN_IN_SUCCESS = 'SIGN_IN_SUCCESS';
export const SIGN_IN_FAIL = 'SIGN_IN_FAIL';

 export function signIn(email, password) {

     return (dispatch) => {
         dispatch({ type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESS });
     }
 }
```

Reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import {
    SIGN_IN_FAIL,
    SIGN_IN_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/';

let authState = { signedIn: false, error: '' }


const authReducer = (state = authState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, signedIn: true }
        case SIGN_IN_FAIL:
            return {...state, signedIn: false, error: action.error }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Try `componentDidUpdate` instead

Comment: componentDidUpdate is also not being called

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` then? If those aren't firing, it's something to do with your setup.

Comment: Some of your code is missing so I can't tell but is LoginScreen a class that's extending Component? Those functions won't fire if you're not inheriting from Component.

Comment: Yes. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Because you executed navigation right inside `render()` function:

```
render() {
    if (this.props.signedIn) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoggedIn');
    }

    return(<View>...</View);
}
```

It must be:

```
render() {
    return !this.props.signedIn && (<View>...</View);
}
```